# Can you iterate through class objects without a list or vector?

Tags: c++, list

Suppose you have a class Class and you create 2 objects

```
  Class *obj1 = new Class();
  Class *obj2 = new Class();
```

I know you can create a list and push_back the objects and then call

```
  for (auto i : list_name) i->function();
```

but is there a way to iterate like this?

```
  for(auto i:Class) i->function();
```

Comment: No you cant iterate using a class name.

Comment: No. Definitely not. How would you iterate over them if there's not relation between them?

Comment: no. Such a feature would require a whole new set of complicated rules that noone wants. Just one example: How do you specify that you want to iterate over `obj1` and `obj2` and not `obj3` that you maybe declared 3 lines above? Why dont you create the objects inside a list in the first place?

Comment: An iterator is any object that, pointing to some element in a range of elements (such as an array or a container), has the ability to iterate through the elements of that range using a set of operators (with at least the increment (++) and dereference (*) operators).

Comment: @BorislavKostov you dont necessarily need an iterator to iterate over elements in a container

Comment: @tobi303: Well, you do if you want to use a range-based for loop. If a container can be put into a range-based for loop, then it has to offer something which fits the iterator concept, even if it's just a pointer.

Comment: @ChristianHackl actually I was thinking about pointers when writing the comment, but of course you are right and pointers indeed are iterators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
for( auto i : { obj1, obj2 } ) i->function();
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/cDviNO)

Comment: Isn't that just a list created inside the braces (`std::initializer_list`)?  It's still a valid solution.  Just checking my understanding of braces.

Comment: @Matt yes that is `std::initializer_list` which can be iterated

Comment: @Powereleven click on live example link then

Comment: oh it was there the whole time :3  Sorry for disturbing

Answer (score 3):

No you can not use a **class name** in place of a *range_expression* inside a [range based loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) as class does not represent a container nor a range of values. You have freestanding instances of `Class`. You would need to store your instances in one of the following:

> - either an array or
> - an object for which begin and end member functions or free functions are defined or
> - a braced-init-list

and then use one of those inside a range based loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear what you want, but you can also register all instances of your `Class` (if it's yours):

```
class Class {
  public:
    static std::set<Class*> instances;
    Class() { instances.insert(this); }
    ~Class() { instances.erase(instances.find(this)); }
    void function();
};
std::set<Class*> Class::instances;
```

and then iterate over all live `Class` instances as follows:

```
Class c;
auto upc = std::make_unique<Class>();
std::vector<Class> vc(4);

for (auto i : Class::instances)
  i->function();
```